# ng-click Button function with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have found this demo in ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A5xZ9/2/)), One thing I am not sure is the okay button they have

`<button ng-click="activity.isEdited = false">Ok</button>`

With this function, I am wondering if we can still add a function inside the ng-click? with something like this?

`<button ng-click="domeSomthing()">Ok</button>`

Can we include both `activity.isEdited = false` and `domeSomthing()`inside the `ng-click?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have a scope function that does both?

```
function doSomething() {
    alert('Done editing');
}
$scope.editedActivity = function(activity) {
    activity.isEdited = false;
    doSomething();
}
```

and in HTML

```
<button ng-click="editedActivity(activity)">Ok</button>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A5xZ9/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<button ng-click="activity.isEdited = false; domeSomthing();">Ok</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure can!

Just add your function to the controllers scope or to a directive. Then you can call it in the ng-click. To use both the function and the Boolean just separate them with a semi-colon